# ERROR: Maximum Call Size Exceeded when Upgraded from Ang V14 -> 15

Tags: primeng, angular15

**Initially had upgraded from Angular 13 -> 14 and it went smooth . Now tried to upgrade to v15 and I face a peculiar issue stating Maximum Call Size Exceeded.**

`npm start`

`cpam-angular-frontend@0.1.0 start`
`ng serve`

`✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.`

`Initial Chunk Files | Names | Raw Size`
`styles.css, styles.js | styles | 2.83 MB |`
`scripts.js | scripts | 1.41 MB |`
`polyfills.js | polyfills | 209.30 kB |`
`vendor.js | vendor | 208.59 kB |`
`runtime.js | runtime | 6.54 kB |`
`main.js | main | 894 bytes |`
`| Initial Total |   4.66 MB`

`Build at: 2024-01-26T09:34:14.596Z - Hash: 8b20185a12f7d4df - Time: 14565ms`

`./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):`
`Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

`./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):`
`Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

``` ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your your textbrowser on ``http://localhost:4200/`` ** ```

`× Failed to compile.`

---

### It Doesn't provide any Information regarding which specific location is causing the issue. So any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Tried to search for any Circular dependencies, couldn't find any such issue.
Tried with every possible solution I could find across the Internet, nothing helped.
Maybe anyone has any approach to follow to debug or get to root cause of the issue.